# Name hiding in c++

Tags: c++, name-hiding

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class ParentClass {
public: 
     virtual void someFunc(int a){
        printf(" ParentClass :: someFunc (int) \n");
    };

    virtual void someFunc(int* a){
        printf(" ParentClass :: someFunc (int*) \n");
    };
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
    virtual void someFunc(int* a){
        printf(" ChildClass ::  someFunc(int*) \n");
    };
};

int main(){
    ChildClass obj;
    /* This function call results in an error: */
    obj.someFunc(7);
}
```

The first one gives error as

```
tr2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
tr2.cpp:27:19: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
     obj.someFunc(7);
                   ^
tr2.cpp:18:18: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'virtual void ChildClass::som
eFunc(int*)' [-fpermissive]
     virtual void someFunc(int* a){
                  ^
```

But if we change the method to accept char instead of int* then

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class ParentClass {
public: 
     virtual void someFunc(int a){
        printf(" ParentClass :: someFunc (int) \n");
    };

    virtual void someFunc(char a){
        printf(" ParentClass :: someFunc (char) \n");
    };
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
    virtual void someFunc(char a){
        cout<<a<<endl;
        printf(" ChildClass ::  someFunc(char) \n");
    };
};

int main(){
    ChildClass obj;
    /* This function call results in an error: */
    obj.someFunc(7);
}
```

output:

```
 ChildClass ::  someFunc(char)
```

With a windows sound(ding). - **ANS: Implicit Conversion here. Please Check the edit below.**

So name hiding works in the first example, but it doesnt in the second example. can anyone explain why? I have also tried making overloaded overridden virtual function with different number of parameters like
int func(int a) , int func (int a, int b), and then overriding only one of them. In that case also name hiding isnt working, the derived class is able to derive the virtual function of base class that isnt overridden.

Why is this name hiding only work only in this particular one case?

**EDIT 1:**

With Context to Eternals Explanation of an implicit conversion. I have another program that should be name hiding but does not. In this version the methods are differentiated on the basis of different no of arguments.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class ABC
{   public:
    ABC()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor ABC"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void meth1(int a);
    virtual void meth2(int a, int b);
};

void ABC :: meth1(int a)
{
    cout<<"One"<<endl;
}   

void ABC:: meth2(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<"Two"<<endl;
}

class BC:public ABC
{
    public:
    BC()
    {
        cout<<"Cons B"<<endl;
    }

    void meth1(int a);
};

void BC :: meth1(int a)
{
        cout<<"Three"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    BC b;
    b.meth1(5);
    b.meth2(6,7);
}
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Shaurya\Desktop>a
Constructor ABC
Cons B
Three
Two
```

Name hiding does not work in this case either.

Comment: As a side note: Why that weird mix of `cout` and `printf()`??

Comment: The 'int' and 'char' overload is ambiguous.

Comment: I copied the example from a website, to see other different cases. The case mentioned in the website was working for name hiding. But the case i tried dont. I use more of cout, and they used printf.

Comment: There's no `int*` in the second version, I don't see how the error message can refer to that. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: the error message corresponds to the first program

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri So I ask you, in your view, what would a function call look like that *would* choose the `char` version?  If it's there, it should be able to be called by some means, so what would the call look like?

Answer (score 6):

When you overload `someFunc()` in `ChildClass`, it hides the two overloads from `ParentClass`. In the first case you are calling a function that takes a `int*` as argument with an integer, so of course it crashes because it cannot do the conversion.

In the second case, you are calling a function that takes a `char` as an argument with an integer, so there is an implicit conversion and everything is fine.

**Update after EDIT 1:**

I don't really get what you were expecting would happen:

- first you construct a `BC`, which is a child from `ABC`, so there is a call to `ABC`'s constructor then `BC`'s
- after that you call `meth1()`: since `BC` overrides it, `BC::meth1()` is called
- finally you call `meth2()`: since `BC` doesn't override it, `ABC::meth2()` is called

The only "name hiding" that happens here is the override of meth1 by BC,but it's not really hiding anything...

Comment: Please check the edit. 
I have considered implicit conversion, That is probably happening there, i didn't notice its the child class function is being called. Anyways i have edited and attached the main problem, where the parent class function is being called , while only one of the method is overridden.

Answer (score 2):

In your "EDIT 1" there's no name hiding. `b.meth2(6,7)` can't find `meth2` in `BC`, so it looks it up in `ABC`. But if you rename `meth2` to `meth1` everywhere in the program, it won't compile because of name hiding: `BC::meth1(int)` will hide `ABC::meth1(int, int)`.

EDIT: Brief explanation of how class member lookup works. When the compiler sees `object.method(args)`, where *static type* of `object` is `class C`, first it looks for the member function `member` in the declaration of `class C`. If it finds it (or it's several overloads), **it stops looking for the `member` anywhere else**. If not, it looks it up in `C`'s base classes following some cryptic rules fully described in the C++ standard part `10.2 Member name lookup`.

Once candidates are found, the compiler checks if any of the candidates can be called with given arguments. If yes, and this can be done unabmiguously, the function is found. Otherwise the program is ill-formed. This process is called *overload resolution* and described in part `13.3` of the standard.

Note that there's no word `virtual` in above explanation.

Comment: Thanks. So this only works in overloaded overridden methods. And the other virtual methods are not affected at all?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. I added short explanation of member lookup to my answer.